# How to get memory location in C# while using structure of C

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I am using C# to record a video from IP camera and I am using `libavcodec57` library for that. So if I need to write or read any property of a structure I need to use `Marshal` class in C#, like

```
int width = Marshal.ReadInt32(in_codecctx, 40);
```

In above `in_codecctx` is of type IntPtr which points `AVCodecContext` structure in C. So there are many properties in that like `width`, `height` etc and to read I need to use above line of code and for that I have to know the address of that property in the memory, which is base address of structure plus offset to that property. Base address I know but how to find actual offset of any property.

One way is, I need to create same structure in C# which is defined in `libavcodec` library and use below code, this will give me offset of width from structure defined in C#.

```
Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(AVCodec.AVCodecContext),"width")
```

But this needs great efforts and still not accurate as it gave me some wrong values.

---

[Update from comment]

[This link](http://wiki.aasimon.org/doku.php?id=ffmpeg:avcodeccontext) is for structure I need to use, is there any way to identify the offset of width and height, if yes how?

Comment: I would say there can be different padding in stuctures in C and C#.

Comment: http://wiki.aasimon.org/doku.php?id=ffmpeg:avcodeccontext This link is for structure I need to use, is there any way to identify the offset of width and height, if yes how?